# Objective c : Using #define constant values in math expressions

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm new to iPhone development and I'm just trying out some simple drawing routines and I'm having trouble using defined values in simple math.

I have a line like this:

```
int offset = (((myValue - min_value) * 6) - middle);
```

and this works fine - but I don't like using the hard coded 6 in there (because I'll use it lots of places.

So I thought I'd define a constant using #define:

```
#define WIDTH_OFFSET 6;
```

then I could use:

```
int offset = (((myValue - min_value) * WIDTH_OFFSET) - middle);
```

however - this gets a compiler error : "Expected Expression."

I can get round this by breaking up the calculation onto several lines:

```
int offset = myValue - min_value;
offset = offset * WIDTH_OFFSET;
offset = offset - middle;
```

The compiler thinks this is fine.

I'm guessing there's some implicit cast or some other language feature at work here - can anyone explain to me what is happening?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Remove the semicolon `;` after `#define`:

```
#define WIDTH_OFFSET 6
```

`#define` substitutes its arguments literally, so your expression after preprocessing becomes

```
(((myValue - min_value) * 6;) - middle);
```

As you can see, there is a semicolon in the middle of the expression, which is a syntax error.

On the other hand, your other expression

```
int offset = myValue - min_value;
offset = offset * WIDTH_OFFSET;
```

does not exhibit such problem, because having two semicolons in a row as in

```
 offset = offset * 6;;
```

is syntactically valid.

Comment: :) Thanks! That makes a lot of sense - one of those rookie errors ;)
As an additional thought - does this mean you could use `#define` with any line of code (like some kind of snippet section)? That could be quite fun :)

Comment: Yes - you can use it anywhere for pretty much anything. Think of the #define as a macro to type in whatever your heart desires. It is extremely powerful, and you can use it conditionally which is like multiplying its power.

Comment: @GirlCalledPete Well, not exactly *any*, but you can certainly have a lot of fun with [preprocessor macro definitions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor#Macro_definition_and_expansion), especially once you start passing parameters to them. Be careful not to get too carried away, though, because overusing preprocessor makes your code unreadable very quickly.

Comment: Sounds very useful - good to learn about these features so I can use them when I get to a tricky bit of code ;) Thanks!

Comment: @GirlCalledPete it's really useful i.e. for min/max functions `#define MAX(x, y) (((x) > (y)) ? (x) : (y))` but, as you can see, the code reability can decrease with more complicated macros

Comment: Actually dasblinkenlight, if used properly, you can increase the legibility of your code. You can make 83 (or what have you) characters one word for example.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight - True, I can see it would be easy to get into spaghetti nightmare if you have too many macro bits of code floating about the place - but useful for those times where you just need to wiggle round something ;)

Comment: @Michał Zygar  Yeah - that could be more concise that having to send a message to a getMax type method - if it gets any more complex I guess you start needing a method to untangle it :)

Answer (score 4):

When you #define something where you use it is *exactly* the same as if you typed it in yourself there. So where you are using WIDTH_OFFSET you are getting 6; in its place - which of course is not your intention. So just remove the semicolon.

Answer (score 2):

As dasblinkenlight said, remove the semi colon.  The explanation for this is that #defines are a literal substitution into your code.  Thus with the semi colon your broken code read:

```
int offset = (((myValue - min_value) * 6;) - middle);
```

The working code read:

```
offset = offset * 6;;
```

Which is syntactically fine as the ;; is effectively a blank 'line' of code.

Comment: And, in the interim period dasblinkenlight edits the post. :D

Comment: :) Thanks for the clarification - even though dasblinkenlight snuck in there quick ;)

Comment: Apparently I need to learn how to type faster. :D Fierce competition for your vote!

Comment: Me too it seems, though I wasted a bit of time checking to see if there was operational diff. between .2 and 02.

Comment: Quick typing seems to be the order of the day - Sometimes it seems I haven't finished typing the question and there are answers already!
I put a +1 on your answers - but I can only accept one! ;)

Answer (score 2):

Basically, macros are convenient functions that are placed inline by the preprocessor. So you can think that they are doing copy/paste for matching entries, in your case it will substitute any occurency of `WIDTH_OFFSET` with `6;` so, just like others said, remover the semicolon `;` and you are all set.

Also, when defining macros for simple math functions, remeber to put them in brackets `(` and `)` otherwise, you could end up with some math operation order bugs( like unintended part multiplication before addition)